# SQL%ROWCOUNT doesn't work to get the number of affected rows

Tags: postgresql

I have following simple code,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_0025()
RETURNS integer AS $$  
DECLARE
r integer := 0;
BEGIN
    insert into t(a,b,c) values (8,8,8);
    r := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    return r;
END;
    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select func_0025();
```

When I run the sql, it complains that `sql doesn't exist in r := SQL%ROWCOUNT;`.

I would ask where the problem is ,thanks.

btw, I am using `PostgreSQL 15.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`

Comment: Yes, because that is illegal syntax. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS).

Comment: `get diagnostics r := ROW_COUNT;` is Postgres' flavour of Oracle's `r := SQL%ROWCOUNT;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postgres you should use `GET DIAGNOSTICS` to get this information.

The updated code should be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_0025()
RETURNS integer AS $$  
DECLARE
    r integer := 0;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t(a, b, c) VALUES (8, 8, 8);
    GET DIAGNOSTICS r = ROW_COUNT;
    RETURN r;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```